# React component not re-rendering when "Date" in state gets updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Disclaimer: I am using React with Typescript.
I have a component which when mounted, sets state with date like this:

```
constructor(props: SomeProps) {
    super(props);
    const fromDate = new Date();
    fromDate.setHours(fromDate.getHours() - fromDate.getUTCDate());
    fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() - 1);
    this.state = {
      fromDate: fromDate,
    };
  }
```

When `componentDidMount()` gets fired, I try to `setState` of `fromDate` once again, if needed:

```
componentDidMount(): void {
  ...someCode
  if (someData.length > 0) {
      const fromDate = new Date(someData[someData.length - 1].timestamp);
      fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() - 1);
      this.setState({
        fromDate
      });
    }
}
```

After setting `fromDate` again (in `componentDidMount()`), I can see in React DevTools (for Chrome), that fromDate has changed, but following DateTimePicker component is not re-rendered:

```
const { fromDate } = this.state;
<DateTimePicker
   value={fromDate.toISOString()}
   label="From"
   dateChangeHandler={(e: any) => this.handleChange(e)}
/>
```

Looking into React DevTools once again, I can see that my main component state has changed for sure, but DateTimePicker has not received new `fromDate` from state.
Does anyone have an idea, why this is not re-rendered?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a typo in your code? `fromTime` was never defined.

Comment: Sorry, did a typo when adding code blocks to stackoverflow (changed it now). No typo in actual code.

Comment: Try to update state in componentDidUpdate() life cycle hook

Comment: This did not do anything

Comment: where is handleChange function?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I should post that next time too :) . Turned out, that my DateTimePicker component had a flaw in it, that's why stuff did not update.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is probably that you are storing Date() object in state, so technically the state has not changed, fromDate is still an object.

You might try with

```
constructor(props: SomeProps) {
    super(props);
    const fromDate = new Date();
    fromDate.setHours(fromDate.getHours() - fromDate.getUTCDate());
    fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() - 1);
    this.state = {
      fromDate: fromDate.toISOString(),
    };
  }
```

And

```
componentDidMount(): void {
  ...someCode
  if (someData.length > 0) {
      const fromDate = new Date(someData[someData.length - 1].timestamp);
      fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() - 1);
      this.setState({
        fromDate: fromDate.toIsoString()
      });
    }
}
```

And then in render

```
const { fromDate } = this.state;
<DateTimePicker
   value={fromDate}
   label="From"
   dateChangeHandler={(e: any) => this.handleChange(e)}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was a good idea to try, but sadly it did not work for me

Comment: Are you sure that your component is rendering again? You can try with `console.log(this.state)` in your `render()` (maybe after `const...`) to see what it outputs.

Comment: "The issue is probably that you are storing Date() object in state, so technically the state has not changed, fromDate is still an object." That's gibberish. If the object's internal data changes, the state will have changed.

Comment: He is doing new Date, so technically it is a new object so the component will render no matter what if the object changes.

Comment: Yes, it is rendering indeed. I saw `fromDate: "2019-11-30T16:57:33.000Z"` (correct) in console.log(this.state), but my stubborn DateTimePicker still shows 2019/12/01 12:09:08 (current time). Even though when I `console.log(fromDate)` at DateTimePicker rendering function, It did receive correct fromDate (DateTimePicker is rendered inside `render()` by function call). I think it might be an issue with my DateTimePicker component afterall, not with setting state.

Comment: @AleksandrH I know that it should change, but not knowing how the DateTimePicker is implemented, I suspected that the main component is re-rendering as it should, but that the DateTimePicker might itself have a problem (which seems still to be the case) with a value being expected to be string, and not an object

Comment: @DamirKasipovic It was the issue indeed. Thanks for your help, console.log really did help me out :)

Comment: @NotADefaultUsername you're welcome :) Usually when something is not behaving as it should, I like to debug the steps that lead to the malfunctioning step. That way it is possible to exactly pinpoint where the issue occurs.